# Authentication Error while connecting to Msolservice using azure functions

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have deployed a function app which includes an azure function that connects to msolservice. But this is producing a Authentication Error recently.
script I am using:

```
$username = 'xxx' 
$password = 'xxx' 
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $(convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
```

Error it produced:
Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unexpected authentication failure.

Function App details
Function runtime: Powershell
runtime version: 3.8.2.0

The user is not MFA enabled.
And I am able to connect it from my local powershell. Any help regarding this issue can be helpful

Comment: try getting the Pscredential using Get-Credential cmdtel

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue come up this week. I fixed it by doing three things:

1. Adding the following line of code to the script before the first connection to force TLS 1.2

   ```
   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
   ```
2. Uninstalling the Azure AD Powershell module from the Windows control panel. This module is obsolete.
3. Installing the new `MSOnline` Powershell module with the following command in a Powershell prompt with administrator permissions:

   ```
   Install-Module -Name MSOnline -Force
   ```

I think the older module must have been using an API or service endpoint that was retired somewhere in the last couple weeks.

---

Separately, it's worth mentioning here the two other common issues I found while troubleshooting this. First, the service account used to make the connection **must** be a full Global Administrator. Second, if this script is to be fully automated the account cannot use MFA. This is going to cause me more problems soon, as we're working on requiring MFA pretty much everywhere.